# Defining template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm given the error: `undefined reference to SE::ShockEvent<sf::Event>::ShockEvent(sf::Event&)` when doing this:

```
    template <class Type> class ShockEvent
        {
        public:
            //event_type will be the enumerator that tells what the event is
            //so we know how to process it
            explicit ShockEvent(Type& event_type);
            virtual ~ShockEvent() {};

        protected:
            virtual std::unique_ptr<ShockEvent> createEvent(Type eventType);

        private:
            ShockEvent();
        };

class ShockUserEvent : public ShockEvent<sf::Event>
    {
    public:
        ShockUserEvent();

    private:
        sf::Event m_event;
    };

ShockUserEvent::ShockUserEvent() :
    ShockEvent<sf::Event>(m_event)
    {

    }
```

In the ShockUserEvent I'm trying to define Type, but it keeps spitting out the error. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Has `ShockEvent(Type&)` been implemented?

Comment: Firstly, if you derive from a class you should not pass references of the members of the derived class down to the constructor of the base class. The members are getting initialized after the base class. Therefore is this a very bad idea. The problem however is, that the constructor is not defined, but only declared.

Comment: @Vinzenz: This depends on a few things, and it is safe as long as the pointer/reference is not used to access the object before the derived type's initialization completes (and before the destructor body completes). It is a bit dangerous, but not *wrong*

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this:

```
explicit ShockEvent(Type& event_type);
```

To this:

```
explicit ShockEvent(Type& event_type) {}
```

Otherwise it's just a declaration without an implementation.

Deeper still, if you're passing `event_type` to this constructor, presumably it's needed for something, so you should either make use of it between the `{` and `}` or discard the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the body of the constructor.